# Universe cardinals and models for ZFC

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals

I'm reading through Joel David Hamkins' [set theory lecture notes](http://jdh.hamkins.org/files/2011/11/Set-Theory-lecture-notes.pdf).  On page 14, on the subject of inaccessible cardinals and submodels of ZFC in $V$, he defines a **universe cardinal** to be a cardinal $\gamma$ such that $V_\gamma$ models ZFC.  For example, if an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ exists, then $\kappa$ is a universe cardinal.  But furthermore, by the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem, there are then lots of models of ZFC inside $V_\kappa$, and Hamkins says that this proves that $\kappa$ is the $\kappa$th universe cardinal.  Specifically, $\{\gamma < \kappa: V_\gamma \prec V_\kappa\}$ is evidently closed in $\kappa$, and is "unbounded by Löwenheim-Skolem".

1. This is confusing to me.  The Löwenheim-Skolem theorem says that $V_\kappa$ contains submodels of arbitrary cardinality.  But in order to have any universe cardinals at all, you need models of ZFC of the form $V_\gamma$, which don't seem to come from Löwenheim-Skolem.  Why should these exist?  Is there something you can do to a model to put it in the form $V_\gamma$?
2. Relatedly, it's also true (this is in Kanamori's *Higher Infinite*) that the only models for *second-order* ZFC are $V_\kappa$ for $\kappa$ inaccessible.  Can someone explain the difference between these two concepts?  I'm finding the distinction between first-order and second-order Replacement a little hair-splitting.

I hope I've phrased this the right way -- I'm a set theory rookie.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: First-order replacement schema is handle the *definable* class function, while second-order replacement axiom can handle arbitrary class function (even the given class function is not definable.)

Comment: @tetori: thanks.  So the idea is that if $V_\kappa$ models second-order ZFC, then every chain of ordinals of length less than $\kappa$ is the image of a function, so $\kappa$ must be regular.  Whereas if $V_\kappa$ just models first-order ZFC, you could evade regularity of $\kappa$ by somehow blocking all these functions from being definable in $V_\kappa$.  Correct?

Comment: @PaulVonKaoghnett I don't think about this part so I don't assure that your arguement is correct. But by Asaf's answer says that the front part of your argument is right.

Comment: It is known that minimal $\kappa$ which $V_\kappa$ makes the model of ZFC is singular; see [related post in Cantor's attic](http://cantorsattic.info/Worldly)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you do need a tiny additional argument to get universe cardinals below an inaccessible $\kappa$. The additional step is an elementary chain argument, which tends to occur relatively frequently.

Starting from an inaccessible $\kappa$, Löwenheim-Skolem gives a small elementary submodel $M_0\prec V_\kappa$. We can then put $M_0$ inside $V_{\alpha_0}$ for some cardinal $\alpha_0<\kappa$. Applying Löwenheim-Skolem again gives a new elementary submodel $V_{\alpha_0}\subseteq M_1\prec V_\kappa$. We then put $M_1$ into some $V_{\alpha_1}$ again. After repeating this $\omega$ many times we get intertwined chains of models $M_n$ of ZFC and initial segments $V_{\alpha_n}$ of the universe which both union up to $V_{\sup \alpha_n}$, which is elementary in $V_{\kappa}$. This implies that $\sup\alpha_n<\kappa$ is a universe cardinal.

By the way, the terminology has shifted slightly since Joel wrote those notes and the term now used for these cardinals is [worldly cardinals](http://cantorsattic.info/Worldly).

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question!  By the way, can you take arbitrary (longer than $\omega$) unions of chains of submodels?

Comment: @PaulVanKoughnett Indeed. The argument is flexible enough to give worldly cardinals of arbitrary cofinality (below $\kappa$).

Comment: What's blocking the application of this argument to show (the false statement) that if $\kappa$ is a $\beth$-fixed point of uncountable cofinality, then there's some $\gamma$ such that $V_\gamma\prec V_\kappa$?

Comment: @JasonZeshengChen Why is that statement false?

Comment: @MihaHabič, oops, I meant unprovable. What I'm thinking is that ZFC proves that if $\alpha,\beta$ are ordinals and $V_\alpha\prec V_\beta$, then $V_\alpha$ is a model of ZFC. ZFC also proves that there are $\beth$-fixed points of uncountable cofinality. So if ZFC were to prove the statement, then ZFC would prove that some $V_\gamma$ is a model of ZFC.

Comment: @JasonZeshengChen I still don't see why $V_\alpha\prec V_\beta$ should imply that $V_\alpha$ models ZFC. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MihaHabič yes, of course. The idea is that $\alpha$ must be strong limit. and if $\varphi$ defines a function $f$ in $V_\alpha$ then it defines one $g$ in $V_\beta$ as well, and $g$ extends $f$. So the range $g$ restricted to any set in $V_\alpha$ will be contained in $V_\alpha$, which is a set in $V_\beta$. Hence  So $f$ itself restricted to any set in $V_\alpha$ also has its range in $V_\alpha$. This can also be found in exercise I.16.8 in the new Kunen or 4.1.7 in Drake.

Comment: @MihaHabič or here at Or here at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521856/a-question-dealing-with-conditions-for-which-v-alpha-models-zfc?rq=1

Comment: @JasonZeshengChen Alright, this is a great question, and it took me a while to figure out. Here is where the argument fails: with the notation of the answer, the model $M_1$ is a small subset of $V_\kappa$. Even thought $V_\kappa=H_\kappa$, you can't conclude that $M_1\in V_\kappa$ if $\kappa$ isn't regular (the transitive closure of $M_1$ is a small union of small sets, but if $\kappa$ is singular it might end up having size $\kappa$ and not appearing in $V_\kappa$). And if $M_1\notin V_\kappa$, the rest of the argument breaks down.

Comment: @MihaHabič ah, I see, so the argument uses regularity in an essential way. This was bothering me yesterday as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Miha gave a very good answer to the first question. Let me add a bit on the second question.

The difference between first-order and second-order replacement is subtle. First-order replacement is a schema, and it says that if $f$ is an internally definable function with a set domain, then its range is a set; whereas the second-order replacement axiom is a single axiom, and it states that whenever $f$ is a subset of $V_\kappa$ which is a function, and its domain is a set of $V_\kappa$, then its range is an element of $V_\kappa$ as well.

If $V_\kappa$ satisfies the second-order axiom, then it $\kappa$ to be regular. To see this note that:

1. If $A\subseteq\kappa$ is an unbounded set, then $A\notin V_\kappa$.
2. Every unbounded set of ordinals is the range of a function which enumerates it.

Now if $\kappa$ is singular, there is some $\gamma<\kappa$, and a function $f\colon\gamma\to\kappa$ which enumerates an unbounded set. This function $f$ is a subset of $V_\kappa$, and its domain is an element of $V_\kappa$, but its range is not.