# Is it provable in $ZFC$ that if $V_\kappa\vDash ZFC$, then $\kappa$ is strongly inacessible?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

The other direction of this implication is pretty obvious, but I'm having a hard time seeing why this direction might be true. I suspect that it isn't, but part of my suspicion comes from my inability to cook up a proof to the contrary and that isn't a particularly reliable guide to the truth. Any help is welcome.

Comment: I'd like to note that this is a very good and natural question, especially if one is familiar with the relation of $H_\kappa$ and $V_\kappa$ for uncountable, regular cardinals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not provable. Quite contrary, it is provably false. More precisely: A cardinal $\kappa$ is **worldy** iff $V_{\kappa} \models \operatorname{ZFC}$. We can prove that the least worldly cardinal (if any exist) has cofinality $\omega$ and hence is far from being inaccessible.

Comment: Any place to look for a sketch of the proof of this?

Comment: @B.Rocke This follows from the Downward Löwenheim Skolem Theorem. Miha Habič posted a sketch of the proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805469/universe-cardinals-and-models-for-zfc).

Comment: Note that while Miha's proof starts with an inaccessible $\kappa$, the same proof goes through for any worldly $\kappa$ of uncountable cofinality.

Comment: In fact an inaccessible cardinal has a club of worldly cardinals below it.

Comment: @Asaf Yes, pretty much by the same proof ;-).

Answer (score 1):

The problematic part is that if $\kappa$ is singular, there might not be any definable first-order function witnessing this. So the only way to find it is essentially to just take the entire power set of $V_\kappa$, and hope to find a short cofinal sequence.

If, however, you replace the schema of Replacement by the second-order statement "*For every function $F$ on $V_\kappa$, and every $x$, the range of $F\restriction x$ is a set in $V_\kappa$*", then it will be true that $\kappa$ is inaccessible. This is an old theorem of Zermelo, and it is very obvious too now:

If $\kappa$ is *not* inaccessible then take a function $F\colon\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)\to\kappa$ witnessing this; extend it to be $0$ elsewhere on $V_\kappa$. Now you have a function $F$ and taking $x=\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ gives you something that $\operatorname{rng}(F\restriction x)\notin V_\kappa$.